# Vertically Align Divs

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am trying to vertically align a div in my code but with no success. This div contains sub divs. The first one

I want this to look like this :

[image]

but at the moment it is not aligned. This is my HTML code :

```css
body {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
.content {
  float: left;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
}
.content h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* the magic */
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
}
.blue {
  background-color: #052D72;
}
.green {
  background-color: #16a085;
}
.red {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="circle blue"></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="circle blue">Blue</div>
  <div class="circle blue"></div>
  <div class="circle blue"></div>
  <div class="circle blue"></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="circle blue"></div>
  <div class="circle blue"></div>
</div>
```

So, in the `.content` I tried adding this :

```
vertical-align:baseline;
```

but I saw no difference.

Comment: have you tired: <div id="content" align="center";>

Comment: align is not valid attribute in HTML5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `display:inline-block` &  Remove `float` for `#content`

```
.content {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 200px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k0fx384a/1/

EDIT with class: https://jsfiddle.net/k0fx384a/2/

Comment: Hi.. the solution is right, but you shouldn't take the same name of id three times... the ID should be unique, so if you want to group some elements and styles, you should take a class. I edited your code. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You have used same `#id` with multiple elements. That is not allowed in HTML across all browsers(seems like IE and FF allow multiple `#id`s).

So just change all the occurances of `id="content"` to `class="content"` and the CSS should start working.

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/MohdAbdulMujib/pen/pbNdPX)

Comment: Sure @Mohd Abdul Mujib. Wrong paste. I had this as a class.

Answer (score 2):

change `<div id="content">` to `<div class="content">` so the styles will be applied.

Comment: Wrong paste. I had this like that it would not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want them both vertically and horizontally aligned, I would recommend using flex. This offers more flexibility and is more forward-facing.

[Mozilla Docs on Flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)

If you use the rules align-items and justify-content, you'll get magic workings. Check out an example: https://jsfiddle.net/vrad7yuj/

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #f00;
}
.col {
  border: 2px solid #00f;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.ball {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="ball"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="ball"></div>
    <div class="ball"></div>
    <div class="ball"></div>
    <div class="ball"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="ball"></div>
    <div class="ball"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative, if you want to do this with a little count of codelines, you can use flexbox:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
}
.content h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* the magic */
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
}
.blue {
  background-color: #052D72;
}
.green {
  background-color: #16a085;
}
.red {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="circle blue"></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="circle blue">Blue</div>
  <div class="circle blue"></div>
  <div class="circle blue"></div>
  <div class="circle blue"></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="circle blue"></div>
  <div class="circle blue"></div>
</div>
```

Take a look on flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Should just be an alternative solution and new knowledge for you. ;-) Cheers.